# setTimeout doesnt fire after first iteration in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have an event that I'm firing every 5 seconds to check if a file has finished processing.

I'm doing the following:

```
if (InSuppArray(item.Id) == false && item.Status() == "Queue") {
    var t = setTimeout(function () { checkQueuedSupp(item.OrderId) }, 5000);
    suppIds.push({ Id: item.OrderId, TimerId: t });
}
```

Basically, multiple files can be uploaded so this created an array of timers and kills them as the files completes.

This works great in Firefox and Chrome, but the timer only fires one time in Internet Explorer.

Is there a better way to do this?  I searched around and found some issues with IE and `setTimeout` but most of those were alluding to the fact that it just never works in IE, which mine at least fires once.

Comment: Instead of creating multiple timeouts instead use `setInterval` which will call your function every 5 seconds until you kill it.

Comment: There are absolutely no issues that I know related to `setTimeout` and IE. You problem must lies somewhere else.

Comment: Where's the trouble causing iteration you've mentioned in the header? There's no iterations in the snippet you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Is is working for first iteration? Yes your code works fine.

2) If repetitive is your problem then check the following:

`setTimeout` is not a repetitive method.  Instead use **`setInterval`**.

```
if (InSuppArray(item.Id) == false && item.Status() == "Queue") {
    var t = setInterval(function () { checkQueuedSupp(item.OrderId) }, 5000);
    suppIds.push({ Id: item.OrderId, TimerId: t });
}
```

To make **`setTimeout`** as repetitive, try to make it has **`recursive`**.

Comment: Interesting, it seems the 5000 ms is slightly different in FF/Chrome and IE because it appeared it was working over there because they'd always end up reading the success message whilst IE would not.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is to delay execute the function, not repeatedly to execute it. What you want is setInterval which will execute your function for every time interval you specified.